# Evaluate Recursive Functions

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I want to evaluate the following recursive function:

F(x) = 0.25*F(2x) when x is between 0 and 0.5 (inclusive);

F(x) = 0.25+0.75*F(2x-1) when x is between 0.5 and 1 (inclusive).

In addition, F(0)=0, F(1)=1. I have no idea how to do this efficiently. What I want to do is to calculate F(x) for a set of [dyadic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) and then plot the graph. The difficult part is to find the function values. Could anyone provide an example on how to deal with such recursive function evaluation, please? At least some reference. What language is suitable for such task, please?

Comment: What does evaluate mean? Do you mean implement? Python or c++ are good languages overall, though python is bit for the "simple" minded people.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson Yes, I want to find the function value for a set of dyadic x's. I am new to this kind of things. Is there some good reference or example for me to study how to do so, please? I have some basic knowledge on Python.

Comment: You realize that your recursive function will cause your program to crash because it is never ending. Forgot to mention matlab too.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson:  There may be a clever way of evaluating it based on the binary representation of x  (0 <= x <= 1).

Comment: For example, if x = 1/2^N, F(x) = (0.25) ^ N.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson I only want to evaluate F at a finite number of x's. I just want to know how to do this efficiently.

Comment: Efficiently? By caching results.  Which language?  Any and all that you've ever heard of.  Here's one in C++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e1cecbc72536eb9

Answer (score 4):

If you're only interested in inputs of the form a / 2<sup>b</sup>, then it might help to define something like

> G(a, b) = F(a / 2<sup>b</sup>)

With this in mind notice that since F(0) = 0 and F(1) = 1, we have that

> G(0, 0) = 0
>
> G(1, 0) = 1

Now, since

> F(x) = 0.25 F(2x)    *(if x ≤ 0.5)*

we see that

> G(a, b) = 0.25 G(a, b - 1) *(if b > 0 and a ≤ 2<sup>b-1</sup>)*

And, since

F(x) = 0.25 + 0.75 F(2x - 1) *(if x ≥ 0.5)*

we see that

> G(a, b) = 0.25 + 0.75 G(a - 2<sup>b-1</sup>, b - 1) *(if b > 0 and a ≥ 2<sup>b-1</sup>)

Overall, we now have to solve this recurrence:

> G(0, 0) = 0
>
> G(1, 0) = 1
>
> G(a, b) = 0.25 G(a, b - 1) if a ≤ 2<sup>b-1</sup>
>
> G(a, b) = 0.25 + 0.75 G(a - 2<sup>b - 1</sup>, b - 1) otherwise

Therefore, to compute F(a / 2<sup>b</sup>), you can do in time O(b) by simply expanding out the above recurrence relation.

Of course, there's the question of whether there's a cleaner explanation for what's going on here. Based on the fact that we're partitioning the unit interval into the ranges [0, 1/2] and [1/2, 1], perhaps it wouldn't hurt to look at the number x in terms of its binary representation. Let's see what happens if we do that.

If x is just one bit long, it's either 0 or 1, and we can evaluate things directly:

> F(0) = 0
>
> F(1) = 1

Now, suppose that x has the binary representation. 0.b<sub>0</sub>b<sub>1</sub>...b<sub>n</sub>. Notice that

2x = b<sub>0</sub>.b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>...b<sub>n</sub>.

That's pretty convenient, because the recursion works out wonderfully if we do this. If b<sub>0</sub> = 0, for example, then we take the first branch:

> F (0.0b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>...b<sub>n</sub>) = 0.25 F(0.b<sub>1</sub>...b<sub>n</sub>)

Otherwise, b<sub>0</sub> = 1, so we take the second branch:

> F(0.1b<sub>1</sub>...b<sub>n</sub>) = 0.25 + 0.75 F(0.b<sub>1</sub>...b<sub>n</sub>)

This can be evaluated in time O(n), where n is the number of bits in the number's representation (this matches the above time bound, since the denominator b from above is our numnber n here. After all, all we did here was change representations).

I haven't looked in depth at what patterns emerge as you try to evaluate this recurrence, but if I spot something, I'll update this answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a damn fine answer. I'm trying to find a closed formula for the answer, but it looks... unlikely that it even exists

Answer (score 2):

It was straightforward to implement in Ruby, which has a built-in `Rational` class so numerical roundoff issues wouldn't haunt you given dyadic numbers.

```
ONE_HALF = Rational(1,2)
ONE_QUARTER = Rational(1,4)
THREE_QUARTERS = Rational(3,4)

def f(r)
  r = r.to_r  # ensure r is a rational
  if r == 0
    return 0
  elsif r == 1
    return 1
  elsif r <= ONE_HALF
    return ONE_QUARTER * f(2 * r)
  else
    return ONE_QUARTER + THREE_QUARTERS * f(2 * r - 1)
  end
end

p f(Rational(0))          # => 0
p f(Rational(1))          # => 1
p f(Rational(1,2))        # => (1/4)
p f(Rational(1,4))        # => (1/16)
p f(Rational(3,4))        # => (7/16)
p f(Rational(47,1024))    # => (1549/1048576)
```